# Django one click action, generate and open multiple PDFs in individual tabs

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to generate multiple (more than one) PDFs and open each PDF in an individual tab for review and follow-up actions.

At the moment I don't want to save PDFs before review, so I use GET method. I use a form to gather configs for PDF generation, and with submit button I open a new tab with a parametrized URL used to generate a PDF. Please find critical elements below.

**urls.py**

```
url(
    r'^tags_list/$',
    view=views.tags_list,
    name="tags_list"
),
url(
    r'^tags/$',
    view=views.generate_pdfs,
    name='report'),
```

**tags_list.html**

```
<form action="/tags/" method="get">
{{ form }
...

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" formtarget="_blank"/>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def generate_pdfs(request, **kwargs):
    # get kwargs
    tags = request.GET.get('tags')
    ...
    response =  reports.pdf1(context)
    #response = reports.pdf2(context)
    #response = reports.pdf3(context)

    return response
```

**reports.py**

```
def pdf1(context):
    html = render_to_string('pdf1.html', context)
    #generate PDF response, I use weasyprint for that
    return response
```

**pdf1.html**

```
<html>...</html>
```

I however failed to find examples on how to open multiple tabs from **views** (Django), may be because of the lack of knowledge (which is well present, the lack of) or that this is impossible (or very hard in Django), or this is a very unorthodox request.

A JS solution to open multiple tabs with slightly different urls wouldn't work for me because of randomized data processing in **models** accessed by **views**; unless this solution would take part of **views** functionality, namely, *read data once and use this data as many times as many PDFs to generate*.

Comment: couldn't you use ajax to pull a json of the required urls and open each of them with JS? The problem is that you are trying to generate multiple pages with one view.

Comment: @Ajurna, I have almost zero JS skills not to mention AJAX. I'm afraid filling the gaps in knowledge would eat up too much time, and it would be easier to develop a basic file management system (which I'm trying to avoid at the moment).

Comment: ok well http is your enemy here. JS is exactly what you need. the only other option is to render a page with all the pdf's in it? using a little ajax and opening windows isn't too hard if you use something like jQuery. You might be stuck in your file management solution.

Comment: @Ajurna, I have randomized data processing in **models** accessed via **views**. Are you sure that with JS/jQuery/AJAX I would be able to use the same data multiple times, -- read data once, use and reuse multiple times? It would mean that I have to generate PDFs using JS-based means, right?

Comment: @Ajurna, other options could be (a) generate PDFs & send via email, (b) generate PDFs, archive, and suggest for download, (c) generate one multi-page PDF (that would include all the PDFs I want to have. But all of these options have downsides. And I fully agree with you on your comment about the file management system.

Comment: I think the best solution is to come up with some sort of "state" that would allow you to generate these pdf's on request. Once that is done most of your problems go away as all you have to do is generate links. personally i would go with option a. That is the simplest solution.